# Change MergeField to text only

Tags: c#, openxml, mergefield

I need to replace text into `MergeField` and do it simply text. I found [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38641424/11563179) on the topic. It works for me. This code changes the text, but leaves the field as `MergeField`. And [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39116458/11563179) that change `MergeField` to text. But if there are several such fields in one line, the second one will be deleted.

At this point, I've tweaked the code from the first link a bit. What do I need to add to change `MergeField` to text?

```
string sourceFile = @"C:\Users\Owl\Desktop\Template.docm";
string targetFile = @"C:\Users\Owl\Desktop\Result.docx";
File.Copy(sourceFile, targetFile, true);
using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(targetFile, true))
{
    document.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

    foreach (FieldCode field in document.MainDocumentPart
                                        .RootElement.Descendants<FieldCode>())
    {
        int indexEndName = field.Text.IndexOf("\\");
        string fieldName = string.Format("«{0}»", 
                                  field.Text.Substring(11, indexEndName - 11).Trim());

        foreach (Run run in document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Descendants<Run>())
        {
            foreach (Text txtFromRun in run.Descendants<Text>()
                                           .Where(a => a.Text == fieldName))
            {
                txtFromRun.Text = "some text";
            }
        }
    }

    document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}
```

**UPDATE**

I made a mistake. The code on the second link. The second field in the line not deleted. It stays. But does not fall into the cycle, is ignored. I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

The code from the [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39116458/11563179) only works when `MergeField` is in different paragraphs. If there are more than one paragraph, only the first `MergeField` will be processed. The rest are ignored.

This is because the parent element is removed.

```
Run rFldCode = (Run)field.Parent; 
...
rFldCode.Remove();
```

The next element of the `foreach` will be from the next paragraph. I mean the first loop of my question code.

### Solution

Collect all parts of a `MergeField` in the `List`.

```
Run rFldParent = (Run)field.Parent;
List<Run> runs = new List<Run>();

runs.Add(rFldParent.PreviousSibling<Run>()); // begin
runs.Add(rFldParent.NextSibling<Run>()); // separate
runs.Add(runs.Last().NextSibling<Run>()); // text
runs.Add(runs.Last().NextSibling<Run>()); // end
```

Picture for clarity. It helped me a lot to understand.

[image]

Now remove these items

```
foreach(Run run in runs)
{
    run.Remove();
}
```

As well as the text field `<w:instrText xml:space="preserve"> MERGEFIELD...`

```
field.Remove(); // instrText
```

And add new text

```
rFldParent.Append(new Text(replacementText));
```

Now, instead of just the `MergeField` is text only.

[image]

### Full code

```
string sourceFile = @"C:\Users\Owl\Desktop\Template.docm";
string targetFile = @"C:\Users\Owl\Desktop\Result.docx";
File.Copy(sourceFile, targetFile, true);
using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(targetFile, true))
{
    document.ChangeDocumentType(WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);

    foreach (FieldCode field in document.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<FieldCode>())
    {
        ReplaceMergeFieldWithText(field, "some text");
    }

    document.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
}

private void ReplaceMergeFieldWithText(FieldCode field, string replacementText)
{
    if (field == null || replacementText == string.Empty)
    {
        return;
    }

    Run rFldParent = (Run)field.Parent;
    List<Run> runs = new List<Run>();

    runs.Add(rFldParent.PreviousSibling<Run>()); // begin
    runs.Add(rFldParent.NextSibling<Run>()); // separate
    runs.Add(runs.Last().NextSibling<Run>()); // text
    runs.Add(runs.Last().NextSibling<Run>()); // end

    foreach(Run run in runs)
    {
        run.Remove();
    }

    field.Remove(); // instrText
    rFldParent.Append(new Text(replacementText));
}
```

## Bonus

To insert different values, you must create a `Dictionary`. Where the key is the `MergeField` name and the value is the text to insert.

To short the field name

```
int indexEndName = field.Text.IndexOf("\\");
string fieldName = field.Text.Substring(11, indexEndName - 11).Trim();
```

For example

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dict.Add("key 1", "value 1");
dict.Add("key 2", "value 2");
dict.Add("key 3", "value 3");

...

foreach (FieldCode field in document.MainDocumentPart.RootElement.Descendants<FieldCode>())
{
    int indexEndName = field.Text.IndexOf("\\");
    string fieldName = field.Text.Substring(11, indexEndName - 11).Trim();

    ReplaceMergeFieldWithText(field, dict[fieldName]);
}
```

Comment: this does not work when merge field text is spread over multiple runs eg. <run>MERGEFIELD</run><run> ABC</run> no existing solutions on stackoverflow work for documents like this.